# How to return new data frame when using a apply function on old dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to return new data frame when using a apply function on old dataframe?

Input Data (df):

bookings  rolling_mean    rolling_std_dev 
ds                 city 
2013-01-01  City_2  69             NaN                NaN 
2013-01-02  City_2  101          NaN                NaN 
2013-01-03  City_2  134         101.333333    32.501282 
2013-01-04  City_2  155         130.000000    27.221315 
2013-01-05  City_2  104         131.000000    25.632011

Code:

```
def f1(x):
    if (math.isnan(x.bookings) or math.isnan(x.rolling_mean) or math.isnan(x.rolling_std_dev)):
        print "Not enough information"
    elif abs(x.bookings-x.rolling_mean) > (2*x.rolling_std_dev):
        print x.bookings
        print x.rolling_mean
        print x.rolling_std_dev

df.apply(lambda x: f2(x), axis = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Problem:

The function above compiles correctly with no errors. However, when I try to run it, it doesn't give me the output I want. It's not printing anything after the elif statement, but it should. Also, I don't understand the dataframe that is showing up with all nones after the printing part of the output. Where is that coming from?

What solution I want:

Return a new dataframe with all the rows that fulfill the elif statement.

Comment: What do you want in the new dataframe? Are you simply trying to remove rows that have `NaN` in them?

Comment: People have explained to you multiple times that inserting images is much less useful than inserting text, because `read_clipboard` doesn't work on images; this is still true.  FWIW, many followers of the pandas tag simply skip questions that don't follow the rules of a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know how read_clipboard works. I fixed it and wont post images again. In this new data frame I want the rows that fulfill the elif statement.

Comment: What are you trying to return in your function?

Comment: Currently I am not returning anything! Which is why the output confuses me. Is it a default return with the apply function?  I want to return a new dataframe with only the rows that fulfill the elif statement. However, not even the printing works in the elif so return x in the elif doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you really want the printing as well?

Comment: No I don't. I only had that in to see if there was a problem with one of the columns or keys to help me figure out why there were nones in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function call does not explicitly return anything, it returns `None` (as all function calls must return something in Python, and default returned value is `None` , if nothing is returned explicitly from the function).

This is why you are getting a dataframe of all `None`. I do not think you can achieve what you are trying for with `apply` , as `apply()` with axis `1` actually runs the function for every row and replaces the row with the returned value (as you see in your case).

What you are trying to do can be achieved in vectorized way using -

```
newdf = df.dropna()
result = newdf[(newdf['bookings'] - newdf['rolling_mean']) > (2 * newdf['rolling_std_dev'])]
```

**Explanation** -

- [`df.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) - This function drops any row with a `NaN` value in it
- Next line does boolean comparison of series (which does same bool comparison for each of its elements and returns a boolean series back) , and then it does [*boolean indexing*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

**Demo** (I changed a row so that there is atleast one row meeting the condition) -

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
                   bookings  rolling_mean  rolling_std_dev
ds         city
2013-01-01 City_2        69           NaN              NaN
2013-01-02 City_2       101           NaN              NaN
2013-01-03 City_2       134    101.333333        32.501282
2013-01-04 City_2       155    130.000000        27.221315
2013-01-05 City_2      1000    131.000000        25.632011

In [51]: newdf = df.dropna()

In [52]: result = newdf[(newdf['bookings'] - newdf['rolling_mean']) > (2 * newdf['rolling_std_dev'])]

In [53]: result
Out[53]:
                   bookings  rolling_mean  rolling_std_dev
ds         city
2013-01-05 City_2      1000           131        25.632011
```